# It is appropriate to include Google Maps screenshot acknowledging it is from Google?

Tags: copyright, internet, licensing

As my web spider was crawling, I found this [site](http://www.hkage.org.hk/en/contact-us). It uses a Google Maps screenshot without using the widget or acknowledging that it is from Google. Is this legal? Should I inform the site to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it's legal, and it's definitely unethical. 
That said, I don't think you have any special responsibility to police Google's intellectual property rights, unless you work for them or something.